# Paypal - How to know if user won't pay his subscription next month?

Tags: paypal

I have made a membership system which uses paypal subscription of $9.9/month. In ipn.php
I can handle if user paid or failed on the first time.

```
<?php

ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

$listener->use_sandbox = true;


try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}


if ($verified) {

// he paid

} else {

// he didn't pay

}

?>
```

However, I don't what if user won't pay his subscription next month. Which method should I consider on to detect this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as simple as 'verified => he paid'. Not by a long chalk. There are several different transaction *types.* You have to *look,* and interpret. One of them is cancellation, another is EOT (end of term), etc.

For example, in this case if you don't get the subscr_payment IPN next month, don't renew the subscription.

Comment: I have these. For example I check the $_POST['payment_status'] if is "Completed". What I ask is, which script/system check it when it comes to next months ?

Comment: I've answered that. If you don't get the subscr_payment, don't renew. Or to put it the other way round, renew when you get the payment, and not otherwise.